# Display processed class names in tabs

Tags: intellij-idea

I already tried to look for an anwser, but with no success.

Recently I joined a new project, where we have a lot of classes which starts with similar beginning, eg. "SomeLongAndAnnoyingPrefix....", as you can imagine this makes tabs with class names very long and there can be only one or two tabs displayed at one time.

So, I would like to see SLAAP instead of "SomeLongAndAnnoyingPrefix" in the tabs, do you know if Intellij provides such a feature?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such feature. It has been a long [requested feature](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-172) to allow for name truncation or limits for the width of editor tabs. Please consider voting for the request.